# How to catch any XHR request?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a way to listen for every single XHR request done inside any tab and to output the result in an `alert()` popup (or in the console if possible). I want to get the headers + request + response.

Here's my code:

`manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Sample APP",
    "description": "Sample Description",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["script.js"]
    }
}
```

`script.js`:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    function(details) {
        alert(details);
    }, 
    {}, 
    []
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try my proposed solution below ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

[**EDIT**: Updated to incorporate **[apsillers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710446/apsillers)**' useful remarks (see comments).]

In the RequestFilter, the `urls` field is mandatory. In order to listen for requests to any URL, use:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    function(details) {
        console.log(details);
    }, { 
        urls: ["<all_urls>"],
        types: ["xmlhttprequest"]   // <-- to narrow down to only AJAX requests
    }, []
);
```

Finally, in order to get the various pieces of info that you are after (headers, request etc), you need to register the appropriate **[event-listeners for the various events](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#events)**. Note you can use the `requestId` property of the `details` argument to link together events that belong to the same request.

Comment: Also, if you want to narrow down to only Ajax, you can specify `{ urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["xmlhttprequest"] }`. The current code will get *all* HTTP requests made while loading each page.

Comment: The suggestion to use multiple event listeners is correct; I'll just add that you can use the `requestId` property of the `details` argument to link together events that belong to the same request.